# Is there a URL that all docker containers have that will return a 200?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to bypass the elastic beanstalk healthchecks for a worker application I have that runs in docker. It is a long story why we want to do this, so please lets focus on what we are trying to do. My googlefoo is failing me today and all I'm getting is how to configure docker to healthcheck my app with http calls and not a way to check docker itself.

To be clear I'm looking for a url that I can configure beanstalk to hit that docker will always respond 200 if it is running.

Thank you in advance

Comment: No that doesn't exist. That would require every docker container to have a specific web server setup in it, which is not the case.

Comment: Do you really need a check for a 200? Or do you just want a health check, that is always "healthy", when the container runs? If so, then just do "docker run --health-cmd 'exit 0' --health-interval=2s alpine sleep infinity". The health command always returns exitcode 0, which means healthy

Comment: sadly for AWS EB I need an successful http.